Exception when using kotlin coroutines to call an api
I am not very good with English, sorry for my possible errors, this is my first question, we have an app developed in Android Studio, which is presenting an error in the kotlinx.coroutines library, below I give more details:
FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
Process: com.*.*.*, PID: 27311
kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutinesInternalError: Fatal exception in coroutines machinery for CancellableContinuation(DispatchedContinuation[Dispatchers.IO, Continuation at com.*.*.*.navs.main.MainViewModel$retrieveVisitsAvailable$1.invokeSuspend(MainViewModel.kt:187)@eaad1db]){Completed}@50e4478. Please read KDoc to 'handleFatalException' method and report this incident to maintainers
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.handleFatalException$kotlinx_coroutines_core(DispatchedTask.kt:146)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:117)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Completed}@5c37aea, Dispatchers.IO]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.CompletedContinuation cannot be cast to kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuation
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher.releaseInterceptedContinuation(CoroutineDispatcher.kt:166)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.ContinuationImpl.releaseIntercepted(ContinuationImpl.kt:118)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:39)

The function that the trace stack flags is the following:
fun retrieveVisitsAvailable(currentLoc: Location) = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    if (connectivityManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        try {
            // The next function call is where the error is marked
            VisitRepository.getVisitsAvailable(
                _uiState.value.preferences!!.userId() !!
            ).collect {
                result - >
                    when(result.status) {
                        HttpResult.Status.SUCCESS - > {
                            resetLoadingMessage()
                            if (result.data != null) {
                                setVisitsOverview(result.data.map {
                                    it.copy(
                                        distance =
                                        if (it.lat != null && it.lng != null) {
                                            SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(
                                                LatLng(currentLoc.latitude, currentLoc.longitude),
                                                LatLng(it.lat.toDouble(), it.lng.toDouble())
                                            ).toFloat() / 1000
                                        } else {
                                            0 f
                                        }
                                    )

                                }.sortedBy {
                                    it.distance
                                })
                                setHSButtonEnabled(true)
                            } else {
                                setErrorMessage(R.string.no_visits_available_lb)
                                //TODO: show message that no visits are available
                                // and block start and end day buttons
                            }
                        }

                        HttpResult.Status.ERROR - > {
                            resetLoadingMessage()
                            result.error ? .printStackTrace()
                            if (isNotConnectionError(result.error ? .javaClass ? .name)) {
                                setRemoteErrorMessage("Hay problemas en la conexión a internet, cargados los datos guardados.")
                            } else {
                                setRemoteErrorMessage(result.message!!)
                            }
                            setVisitsOverview(null);
                            //TODO: block start and end day buttons
                        }

                        HttpResult.Status.LOADING - > {
                            setLoadingMessage(R.string.retrieving_visits_overview_lb)
                        }
                    }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        setVisitsOverview(null);
    }
}

According to what I have debugged, the function is executed correctly, if there is a connection the call is made to the api and the information is received correctly, it is returned and completed, but after a while the exception appears and the app closes, the try catch does not seem to have any effect nor does there seem to be any more executions of the function, this function is executed at the beginning of the app, since it loads essential information for its operation, a process that is working correctly, but the failure always occurs, whether immediately or after a few seconds or minutes (maximum 2).
These are the subsequent calls:
class VisitRepository {
    companion object {
        suspend fun getVisitsAvailable(userId: Long): Flow <HttpResult<List<Visit>>> {
            return flow {
                emit(HttpResult.loading())
                val result = VisitsDataSource.getVisitsAvailable(userId)
                emit(result)
            }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        }
    }
}

// VisitsDataSource
class VisitsDataSource {
    companion object {
        private val dataService = RESTClient.getService(Service::class.java)
        suspend fun getVisitsAvailable(userId: Long): HttpResult<List<Visit>> =
            RemoteDataSource.parseResponse {
                dataService.getVisitsAvailable(userId)
            }
    }
}

// RemoteDataSource.parseResponse
interface RemoteDataSource {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        suspend fun <T> parseResponse(request: suspend() -> Response <T> ): HttpResult <T> {
            var fallbackMessage = "Hubo un error inesperado"
            var httpStatus = 0
            return try {
                println("Making http request in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                val result = request.invoke()
                httpStatus = result.code()
                if (result.isSuccessful) {
                    return HttpResult.success(result.body(), result.code())
                } else {
                    val errorResponse =
                        RESTClient.instance!!
                        .responseBodyConverter<JSONObject> (JSONObject::class.java,
                            arrayOfNulls(0)).convert(result.errorBody() !!)
                    Log.e("REMOTE", errorResponse ? .toString() ? : "ERROR")
                    HttpResult.error(errorResponse ? .optString("ERROR", fallbackMessage) ?
                        : fallbackMessage, null, httpStatus)
                }
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Log.e("REMOTE", "", e)
                if (e is java.net.SocketTimeoutException) {
                    fallbackMessage = "No se completó la petición al servidor a tiempo"
                }
                HttpResult.error(fallbackMessage, e, httpStatus)
            }
        }
    }
}

// dataService
interface Service {
    @GET("/fake-uri")
    suspend fun getVisitsAvailable(
        @Path("userId") userId: Long
    ): Response <List<Visit>>
}

It was debugged, the function seems to execute and conclude the process correctly, the server response is correct, the data is displayed correctly in the app, but the exception is thrown after a while, and the app closes completely.
The libraries were updated, here are the currently used versions.
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.9.24"
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.3" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version kotlinVersion apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "$kotlinVersion-1.0.20" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics") version "2.9.9" apply false
}

dependencies {
    val lifecycleVersion = "2.7.0"

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")

    //LifeCycle
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycleVersion")

    //[START] Jetpack Compose
    val navVersion = "2.7.7"

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.9.0")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    // Integration with ViewModels
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycleVersion")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycleVersion")

    // Navigation between composables
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navVersion")
    //[END] Jetpack Compose

    // alternative to shared preferences
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.1.1")

    // Camera and scanner
    val cameraxVersion = "1.3.3"
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-core:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$cameraxVersion")
    implementation("com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0")

    //Location
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.2.0")

    //Http client
    implementation(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.11.0"))
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp")
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")

    //Room
    val roomVersion = "2.6.1"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

    //Firebase
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.0.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")

    //Google Maps
    implementation("com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:4.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:3.4.0")

    //[START] Testing Dependencies
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    testImplementation("androidx.test:core:1.5.0")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.05.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    //[END] Testing Dependencies
}

I appreciate any kind of help, including alternatives to replace the use of kotlin.coroutines or solve the current use, I have been researching and testing for about 2 days without success.
Thank you so much.

Can you please condense your code into a [mre]?
